# Add QGSExpression to QGraphicsItem in Layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to add and modify and expression for Opacity in a QGraphicsLineItem

when I have the item QGraphicsLineItem, it not have a variable to modify the opacity expression

Code to get the item:

```
QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0].items()[0]
```

Comment: QGraphicsLineItem doesn't have a direct method to set opacity. Opacity is controlled via the QPen used to draw the line.

Comment: @iskandarblue, I understand you, but how can I modify a qgsexpression by PyQGIS in this case ?

Comment: @iskandarblue, the QGraphicsLineItem is a child of QGraphicsItem, that have the opacity attribute, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to read and modify the opacity expression for any item of the Layout in the following way:

```
items = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0].items()

for item in items:
    # Visualize the current expression
    expression = item.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.Opacity).asExpression()
    print(expression)

    # Modify the previous expression of Opacity
    item.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.Opacity).setExpressionString('if(@atlas_pagename = 6, 100, 0)')

    # Visualize the modified expression
    print(item.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.Opacity).asExpression())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPen, QColor
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsLineItem

line_item = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()[0].items()[0]

pen = line_item.pen()

color = pen.color()
color.setAlpha(128)  # Set to 50% opacity

pen.setColor(color)
line_item.setPen(pen)
```

Comment: You may change your imports e.g `from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QPen, QColor` and
`from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QGraphicsLineItem` for portability among QGIS 3.x versions and associated Qt installed versions.